# SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, json, express, server, fetch

I have an error with request to express. I have this fetch:

```
fetch(`http://localhost:4200/dist/js/server.min.js`, {
    method: "POST",
    // mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(`<html><body><div style="background-color: yellow;"><p>Hello World!</p></div></body></html>`),
  }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
  })
```

And I have such a code for my express server:

```
const { exec }   = require("child_process"),
      express    = require("express"),
      bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
      webshot    = require('webshot'),
      PORT       = 4200,
      app        = express(),
      cors       = require('cors')

// app.use(cors())

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4242');
    res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST', 'GET', 'OPTIONS');
    res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
    res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    next();
    
});

// app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/dist/js/server.min.js', (req, res) => {
    res.send('<h1>Hello</h1>')
})

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    htmlData = req.body
    screen(htmlData) // just my function
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`What's my age again? ${PORT}, I guess.`)
});
```

And I've got this error in browser:

```
POST http://localhost:4200/dist/js/server.min.js 400 (Bad Request)
```

And this in console:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (/home/joe/Documents/vscode-projects/html-projects/swipeskins/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:158:10)
    at parse (/home/joe/Documents/vscode-projects/html-projects/swipeskins/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
    at /home/joe/Documents/vscode-projects/html-projects/swipeskins/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (/home/joe/Documents/vscode-projects/html-projects/swipeskins/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at done (/home/joe/Documents/vscode-projects/html-projects/swipeskins/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/joe/Documents/vscode-projects/html-projects/swipeskins/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:198:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1139:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:17)
```

I guess, server has problems with parsing json data. But why? What is wrong with code?

Thanks a lot for your time, I would be very grateful to hear something from you if you have some thoughts about my situation.

Comment: this error mean that the json is not contracted correctly, and that the problem is in position 0 meaning the start of the json, can you add the json, or at  least it start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON's top level data type is a string:

> ```
> JSON.stringify(`<html>...</html>`);
> ```

The *current* version of the JSON specification allows the top level data type in the JSON text to be **any** JSON data type.

The *original* version only allowed an object or an array.

The error message says that having `"` as the first character is an error, which implies that it doesn't support strings as the top level data type (and thus implements the original specification).

---

Either change the structure of the JSON so it starts with an object or an array:

```
{
    "html": "<html>...</html>"
}
```

or change the data format you are sending:

```
"Content-Type: text/html"
```

and

```
 body: "<html>...</html>" // without JSON.stringify
```

---

Obviously, you'll need to change the server-side code to accept the changed format.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the express JSON body parser by default only accepts inputs that can be parsed as JSON *objects*. However, you can change it to accept other types of valid JSON data (including strings, like in the OP) by disabling "strict" parsing:

```js
app.use(express.json({strict: false}));
```

This is the workaround the worked for me.

Reference: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/1725#issuecomment-22844485

Answer (score -1):

On request body you are not parsing a DOM element, so you can do the following:

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const raw = '<html><body><div style="background-color: yellow;"><p>Hello World!</p></div></body></html>';
const body = parser.parseFromString(raw, 'text/html');

fetch(`http://localhost:4200/dist/js/server.min.js`, {
    method: "POST",
    // mode: 'no-cors', // If you use 'no-cors' you will not get response body and some headers
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
  })
```

Comment: Running a DOM element through `JSON.stringify` isn't going to give you a useful result! https://jsbin.com/kidezivolu/1/edit?js,console